# KDE Plasma 5 Isolate audio to the virtual desktop of the program playing it

Tags: sound, kubuntu, kde, plasma, plasma-5

I am running Kubuntu 20.04 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.18.5 and I would like to set up my system such that any program playing audio may only be heard on virtual desktops where said program my be seen.

As an example if I had a music player open on desktop 1 and a YouTube video playing on desktop 2 I would like to only be able to hear the music if I were on desktop 1 (and vice versa with the video playing on desktop 2).

It would be preferable, but not required, for programs pined to all desktops to be heared on all desktops.

Thank you for your time.